# Transforming a nested list for textual output

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

Hello I have a data structure based on lists, with items, subitems and subsubitems, and I want to display a textual output with a description.

```
ITEM = {"Item one", "Item two"};
SUBITEM = {{"subitem a", "subitem b"}, {"subitem a"}};
SUBSUBITEM = {{{"subsubitem 1", "subsubitem 2", "subsubitem 3", 
 "subsubitem 4"}, {}}, {{"subsubitem 1"}}};
```

(Of course this is a simpler version of my case) 
Ideally I'd like to produce text as

```
Item one with subitems:
subitem a and sub-sub-items:
subsubitem 1
subsubitem 2
subsubitem 3
subsubitem 4
subitem b and sub-sub-items:
Item two with subitems:
subitem a and sub-sub-items:
subsubitem 1
```

Coming from a procedural attitude I have written

```
TEXT = Module[{tmp = ""},
  For[i = 1, i < Length[ITEM] + 1, i++, tmp = tmp <> ToString[ITEM [[i]]] <> " with subitems:\n";
     For[j = 1, j < Length[SUBITEM[[i]]] + 1, j++,tmp = tmp <> ToString[SUBITEM[[i, j]]] <> " and sub-sub-items:\n";
        For[k = 1, k < Length[SUBSUBITEM[[i, j]]] + 1, k++,tmp = tmp <> ToString[SUBSUBITEM[[i, j, k]]] <> "\n"]]];
            tmp]
```

but I am sure there exist some more elegant solution using StringJoin and Map at different levels.

Any suggestion?

Paolo

Comment: Is the initial data structure (ITEM={...},SUBITEM={...},...} imposed to you ? Are these data generated by an external program in that particular way ? Are you free to choose another data structure?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mix of `Transpose` and `Map` to create the structure:

```
Transpose[{ITEM, Transpose /@ Transpose[{SUBITEM, SUBSUBITEM}]}]
```

> ```
> {{Item one, {{subitem a, {subsubitem 1, subsubitem 2, subsubitem 3, subsubitem 4}}, {subitem b, {}}}}, {Item two, {{subitem a, {subsubitem 1}}}}}
> ```

Then add your title text to the `ITEM` and `SUBITEM` elements, and join everything together.

```
itemTitle = " with subitems:";
subItemTitle = " and sub-sub-items:";

StringJoin[Riffle[Flatten[
  Transpose[{ITEM /. s_String :> s <> itemTitle, 
    Transpose /@ Transpose[{SUBITEM /. s_String :> s <> subItemTitle, SUBSUBITEM}]
  }]
], "\n"]]
```

> ```
> "Item one with subitems:
> subitem a and sub-sub-items:
> subsubitem 1
> subsubitem 2
> subsubitem 3
> subsubitem 4
> subitem b and sub-sub-items:
> Item two with subitems:
> subitem a and sub-sub-items:
> subsubitem 1"
> ```